# "IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10" when running inference on Coral Dev Board

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, edge-tpu

I'm trying to run a quantized and Edge-TPU-compiled Tensorflow object detection model on a Coral Dev Board.

My Code:

```
import time
import os

from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

from pycoral.adapters import common
from pycoral.adapters import detect
from pycoral.utils.dataset import read_label_file
from pycoral.utils.edgetpu import make_interpreter

model_path = '/mnt/ssd1/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite'
label_path = '/mnt/ssd1/meteor-labels.txt'
img_directory = "/mnt/ssd1/test_images/"
img_filenames = os.listdir(img_directory)
count = 5
threshold = 0.2
output_path = "/mnt/ssd1/detection_output/"

labels = read_label_file(label_path) if label_path else {}
interpreter = make_interpreter(model_path)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()


def draw_objects(draw, objs, label_data):
    """Draws the bounding box and label for each object."""
    for obj in objs:
        bbox = obj.bbox
        draw.rectangle([(bbox.xmin, bbox.ymin), (bbox.xmax, bbox.ymax)],
                       outline='red')
        draw.text((bbox.xmin + 10, bbox.ymin + 10),
                  '%s\n%.2f' % (label_data.get(obj.id, obj.id), obj.score),
                  fill='red')


def run_inference(image, index):
    _, scale = common.set_resized_input(
        interpreter, image.size, lambda size: image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS))

    print('----INFERENCE TIME----')
    print('Note: The first inference is slow because it includes',
          'loading the model into Edge TPU memory.')
    for _ in range(5):
        start = time.perf_counter()
        interpreter.invoke()
        inference_time = time.perf_counter() - start
        objs = detect.get_objects(interpreter, threshold, scale)
        print('%.2f ms' % (inference_time * 1000))

    print('-------RESULTS--------')
    if not objs:
        print('No objects detected')

    for obj in objs:
        print(labels.get(obj.id, obj.id))
        print('  id:    ', obj.id)
        print('  score: ', obj.score)
        print('  bbox:  ', obj.bbox)

    if output_path:
        image = image.convert('RGB')
        draw_objects(ImageDraw.Draw(image), objs, labels)
        image.save(os.path.join(output_path, f"{index}.jpg"))
        # image.show()


for i, path in enumerate(img_filenames):
    run_inference(Image.open(os.path.join(img_directory, path)).convert('RGB'), i)
```

When running it via "mdt shell", it throws the following error:

```
----INFERENCE TIME----
Note: The first inference is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detect_devboard.py", line 86, in <module>
    run_inference(Image.open(os.path.join(img_directory, path)).convert('RGB'), i)
  File "detect_devboard.py", line 65, in run_inference
    objs = detect.get_objects(interpreter, threshold, scale)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pycoral/adapters/detect.py", line 237, in get_objects
    return [make(i) for i in range(count) if scores[i] >= score_threshold]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pycoral/adapters/detect.py", line 237, in <listcomp>
    return [make(i) for i in range(count) if scores[i] >= score_threshold]
IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10
```

The Dev Board runs Mendel Linux and has Python 3.7.3 and pycoral 2.0.0 installed.

What can I do to be able to successfully run the inference?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. This looks like an issue for the Pycoral devs, not here. The message clearly implies that `range(count)` does not create correct indices for `scores`; presumably `count` should be equal to `len(scores)` but isn't. However, all of those are variables in the library code, not your code; and they don't have obvious connections to the parameters that you're passing in. You should start by checking the documentation, and then ask on whatever issue tracker etc. they have about the ultimate cause of such an error.

Comment: Okay, so I contacted the Coral Support and they helped me resolve the problem. I'm now going to post an answer below to help anyone encountering this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the PyCoral API. To solve the issue, I replaced the last line from the "detect.py"-file (in my case located in "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pycoral/adapters/detect.py") with this updated line:

`return [make(i) for i in range(len(scores)) if scores[i] >= score_threshold]`

Comment: Hopefully they'll have this patched in the next release, then.